# Create input groups within forms and access them via POST in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to create inputs groups and access them via `$_POST` with PHP in a associative-array way? I have a form where user can input information about products. Each product has a name and a description.

**Simple solution**

In a typical form, I would create a HTML structure like:

```
<form method="post" id="insert" action="test.php">
  <!-- First product -->
  <input type="text" name="title1"/>
  <input type="text" name="description1"/>

  <!-- Second product -->
  <input type="text" name="title2"/>
  <input type="text" name="description2"/>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert products" />
</form>
```

and access data via PHP with:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo 'Submitted data:<br/>';
  echo 'title='.$_POST['title1'].' description='.$_POST['description1'].'<br/>';
  echo 'title='.$_POST['title2'].' description='.$_POST['description2'].'<br/>';
}
```

**Tricky (but harder) pseudo-solution**

What I would like to create is a HTML pseudo-code where product inputs are grouped in structures with a title and a description, like this:

```
<form method="post" id="insert" action="test.php">
  <!-- First product -->
  <div name="products[]">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="description"/>
  </div>

  <!-- Second product -->
  <div name="products[]">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="description"/>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert products" />
</form>
```

PHP pseudo-code to access inputs:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo 'Submitted data:<br/>';

  foreach($_POST["products"] as $product)
  {
    echo 'title='.$product['title'].' description='.$product['description'].'<br/>';
  }
}
```

Is it feasible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use a grouping name for that attribute so that when it is submitted it is grouped. The group `name=""` in that div is incorrect, it must be on the input elements. Example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $products = $_POST['products']; // assuming they are all filled, they will be here inside
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($products); // check the results
}


?>

<form method="post" id="insert" action="">
  <!-- First product -->
  <!-- group them by row index -->
  Title: <input type="text" name="products[1][title]"/>
  Description: <input type="text" name="products[1][description]"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <!-- Second product -->
  Title: <input type="text" name="products[2][title]"/>
  Description: <input type="text" name="products[2][description]"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert products" />
</form>
```

Super basic insertion example (this is just an example, you can use it or not):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $products = $_POST['products'];

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `table_name` (`title`, `description`) VALUES (?, ?)');
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $insert->bind_param('ss', $product['title'], $product['description']);
        $insert->execute();
    }
    $insert->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghost. I suppose it's impossible to avoid using indexes 1,2,... in HTML form, isn't it?

Comment: @Giorgio of course you need those indices, they are the ones that sets whether its a grouped row, if you didn't put them `[]`, titles, and descriptions will be grouped, not the ones that are according to their respective rows

Comment: @Giorgio and also in this way they are easy to manage in a loop, i'l give up a sample insertion code, this is just an example, you can use it or not, just to give a basic idea